# Why doesn't the ensureCapacity() method of ArrayList increase the size of the list?

Tags: java, arraylist, size

When I execute the below code, I get output as `1`. Why does this happen?

```
import java.util.*;

class Output {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList obj = new ArrayList();
    obj.add("A");
    obj.ensureCapacity(3);
    System.out.println(obj.size());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size()) refers to the number of elements that are actually in the `List`, not the size of the backing array.

[Documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size())

> `public int size()`
>
> Returns the number of elements in this list.

The idea behind the implementation of `ArrayList` is that you should rarely care how big the size is *exactly*, you should only care that it's big enough (controlled with [`ensureCapacity()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity(int))), and not too big (controlled with [`trimToSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize())). But most of the time, you don't need to know or care the size of the backing array.

Answer (score 2):

`size()` tells you number of number of elements of in the arraylist. On the other hand by `ensureCapacity(n)` you are telling the arraylist that you are going to have at least `n` elements.

Arraylist grows dynamically, say it starts with an initial capacity of `x`, once this capacity is about to over, it creates a new array of size `2x`. If this is also about to over then `4x`. While doubling the array size there is a overhead, you have to copy all the elements.

But in the starting itself, if you know that you are going to have at least `10x` elements, then you can ask the arraylist to ensure at least `10x` capacity by using `ensureCapacity(10x)`so that you can avoid all the overhead.